# высчитать и записать разницу времени

Tags: mysql

В БД хранится дата в формате 2017-03-24 04:05:10

Как составить mysql-запрос чтобы проделать операцию `2017-03-24 04:56:17` - `2017-03-24 04:05:10` = `2017-03-24 00:51:07`?

Нашел `TIMEDIFF`, которая возвращает только время, требуется сохранить и дату, при этом известно что разница во времени не превышает 24 часа (т.е. дата не меняется).

Comment: Как вариант можно в лоб, если дата не меняется SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT('2017-03-24 04:56:17', '%Y-%m-%d '), TIMEDIFF('2017-03-24 04:56:17','2017-03-24 04:05:10'));

Answer (score 0):

> Как составить mysql-запрос чтобы проделать операцию `2017-03-24 04:56:17 - 2017-03-24 04:05:10 = 2017-03-24 00:51:07`?

Повнимательнее посмотрите на свою "операцию"... она должна быть либо `дата-интервал=дата`, либо `дата-дата=интервал`. В первом случае используйте функцию DateDiff, во втором DateAdd.

А разность двух дат никак не может быть датой...

Comment: Можете привести рабочий пример?